# How to detect orientation of View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have three view controller both are which are pushed on the navigation controller which I have subclassed in order to allow rotation in only Second View Controller, I do it like this,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{    
  if ([self.topViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
      return YES;

  return NO;
}
```

I write this piece of code in my Custom Navigation Controller, The problem is that if I open my application in portrait mode and then change the orientation to landscape mode my View Controller does not rotate but even when my Second View Controller opens up it opens in portrait mode although I expect it to open in landscape mode as it supports rotation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: does it rotate when you move your device to portrait and back?

Comment: Have you implemented `func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask`?

Comment: Yeah it rotates fine after Second View Controller opens up and I rotate device

Comment: Do you have to push? or would presenting the view be ok?

Comment: I am pushing the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` during navigation. You should override  push/pop methods to call `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` with a small UI delay (`dispatch_async`)

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];

    [self updateOrientaion];
}

- (nullable UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self updateOrientaion];

    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([self.topViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (void)updateOrientaion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
    });
}

@end
```

But when you pop to rootViewController of the `UINavigationController` `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called for the rootViewController. So you also need to implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` for the FirstViewController

```
@implementation FirstViewController

.......

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked! Although when my second view controller loads there is a slight animation how can I stop the animation because it gives the user a feel of rotation.

Comment: Been looking for this solution for a while.  Thank you!